# What effect does declaring the various <accessor style> tags in SDEF have?

Tags: cocoa, applescript

When I declare elements in the .sdef file for my scriptable application, I have the option to declare various accessors, like this:

```
<accessor style="id"/>
<accessor style="index"/>
```

However, I wonder what consequence these declarations have. So far, I could not make out any changes of behavior in my test scripts whether I add or remove accessors for index and id as long as I implement the necessary methods.

So, how do these affect anything? Are they only for documentary purposes, such as what is shown in the dictionary of the Script Editor?

Or does the scripting engine actually behave differently in certain cases depending on these declarations?

So far, I only noticed one behavior that affects them: [Script Debugger](http://www.latenightsw.com) appears to use them to decide how to browse values in its Explorer. But I doubt Apple added these declarations only for the purpose of this application.

Comment: AppleScript does not validate against these settings in your SDEF.  However, other tools may.  For instance, my Script Debugger application uses this information to control the object access options presented to the user in its Explorer viewers.  

Various AppleEvent bridges may also use this information to control the kinds of object access they provide to their host scripting languages.  An example from the distant past was my JavaScriptOSA project which bridged AppleEvent access into JavaScript.  It used the key form settings to control the keys one could use when accessing element objects.

Comment: Thanks. Why not turn this into a full answer? It would be justified, I think, and you get more rep points that way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppleScript does not validate against these settings in your SDEF. However, other tools may. For instance, my Script Debugger application uses this information to control the object access options presented to the user in its Explorer viewers. Various AppleEvent bridges may also use this information to control the kinds of object access they provide to their host scripting languages. An example from the distant past was my JavaScriptOSA project which bridged AppleEvent access into JavaScript. It used the key form settings to control the keys one could use when accessing element objects.